# How can I efficiently insert a Float32Array into a Float32Array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert a Float32Array in the middle of anther Float32Array. I am currently creating a new Float32Array and using 3 for loops to insert elements into this new Float32Array (1 for before the insertion, 1 for inserting the new Float32Array, and 1 for after the insertion).

This is taking a long time. Is there a faster way to insert a Float32Array into another? For instance, is there functionality akin to

```
// Suppose originalArray and insertedArray are 2 Float32Arrays of
// lengths 100000 and 5000 respectively, and I want to insert 
// insertedArray into originalArray at element 50000.

var combinedArray = new Float32Array(105000);
combinedArray.set(originalArray.subarray(0, 50000));
combinedArray.subarray(50000, 55000).set(insertedArray);
combinedArray.subarray(55000, 105000).set(originalArray.subarray(50000, 100000));
```

Currently, the above code does not work because the `subarray` method does not return a value with a `set` method pertinent to the entire `Float32Array`.

Comment: You will need to do your 3 loops to insert the data as desired. All combinedArray.set(originalArray.subarray(0,50000)) is doing is looping through the originalArray's indices as it is. The two following commands would also require looping through the entire arrays as these operations cannot perform more quickly than O(n) since all n values need to be copied.

Maybe you can explain what problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: I have loaded 6MB of file data into javascript `Float32Array`s. I am trying to insert one `Float32Array` of 2 million elements into one of 3 million elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something you can do in just a bunch of instructions:

```
var combinedArray = new Float32Array(105000);
combinedArray.set(originalArray);
[].splice.apply(combinedArray, [50000, 0].concat([].slice.call(insertedArray, 0)));
```

I don't really know about its performances, though. I fear that `combinedArray` is somehow converted into an `Array`, thus taking a lot of memory and maybe CPU occupation. It shouldn't, but I'm not sure.

Anyway, the `set` method has a [second optional argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array#set%28%29), i.e. is the offset of the array from where the new elements must be set. So, your last two lines would become:

```
combinedArray.set(insertedArray, 50000);
combinedArray.set(originalArray.subarray(50000, 100000), 55000);
```

Maybe this is more efficient.

**Edit**: it is, according to [this test](http://jsperf.com/inserting-elements-in-typed-arrays). So, you have your way.